# I am getting error for isDisplayed method?

Tags: selenium, appium, nosuchelementexception

if (driver.findElement(By.id(id)).isDisplayed()) {

}

Always execution is failed when element is not available?

Environment:

Appium 1.15.1

java Client 7.3.0

selenium-java 3.141.59

error logs:

Android Loding Problem Pages

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Can't locate an element by this strategy: By.chained({By.AccessibilityId: OK})
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.findElement(AppiumElementLocator.java:126)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.interceptors.InterceptorOfASingleElement.intercept(InterceptorOfASingleElement.java:59)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d311658.isDisplayed()
    at 
    at ✽.And Verify the On Side Menu List are Navigating to correspont Screen with OnBoared User(:12)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator$WaitingFunction@66ba7e45 (tried for 1 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:304)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.waitFor(AppiumElementLocator.java:99)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.findElement(AppiumElementLocator.java:119)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.interceptors.InterceptorOfASingleElement.intercept(InterceptorOfASingleElement.java:59)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d311658.isDisplayed()
    at 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:39)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:79)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:70)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.chained({By.AccessibilityId: OK})
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Elites-MacBook-Pro-4.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1c56:6e8a:fceb:a653%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.3', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.builder.ByChained.findElement(ByChained.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:57)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.findElement(IOSDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.ContentMappedBy.findElement(ContentMappedBy.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:57)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.findElement(IOSDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.lambda$0(AppiumElementLocator.java:120)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator$WaitingFunction.apply(AppiumElementLocator.java:172)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator$WaitingFunction.apply(AppiumElementLocator.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
    ... 67 more

Comment: element is on screen? in appium if element is not screen it will return false

Comment: that was the alert Ok popup. Not displayed

Comment: Basically you want it should return true or false but it should not fail?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom isDisplayed method here with some explicit wait. Something like this

```
protected boolean isDisplayed(WebElement id, long timeOutInSeconds) {
        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(DriverManager.getDriver(), timeOutInSeconds);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(id));
        } catch (TimeoutException | NoSuchElementException ex) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And then apply to your element like this:

```
if (!isDisplayed(ELEMENTNAME, 10)) {
            Assert.fail("");
        } else {
            Log.info("");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to verify element is displayed on the page, you can try out this:

```
List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.id(id));
```

This would return the list of elements matching the id you provided. If the List size is more than 0 it means that the element is present on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `custom` function for mobile element’s `visibility`.

```
public boolean checkMobileElementExist(By by)  {
        boolean objectExist = false;
        try {
            objectExist = element.findElement(by).isDisplayed();

        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }

        return objectExist;
    }
```

Now you can use this function in you code

```
if (checkMobileElementExist(By.id(id))) {
}
```